# Return a document with query in firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to return a document from a function using Firestore. Here is my query:

```
public class func getProductsInShoppingList(name:String = "Default") -> DocumentSnapshot?{
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let userId: String! = defaults.string(forKey: "UserUUID")

    var doc:DocumentSnapshot?
    db.collection("shoppingLists")
        .whereField("users." + userId, isEqualTo: true)
        .whereField("name", isEqualTo: name)
        .limit(to: 1)
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    doc =  document
                    break
                }
            }
    }
    return doc
}
```

This is obviously an async operation. What is the proper way to return and use the document. Notification? Call back? Thanks

Comment: here as you just getting one document You can make use of notificationObserver that will notify you When operation is completed and you can Call required Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as in DidLoad just add a observer as

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Add notification Observer to get status out of Async mode
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DocumentReceived"), object: nil)

    }
```

Now in your function

```
public class func getProductsInShoppingList(name:String = "Default") -> DocumentSnapshot?{
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let userId: String! = defaults.string(forKey: "UserUUID")

    var doc:DocumentSnapshot?
    db.collection("shoppingLists")
        .whereField("users." + userId, isEqualTo: true)
        .whereField("name", isEqualTo: name)
        .limit(to: 1)
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    doc =  document
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DocumentReceived"), object: nil)
                    break
                }
            }
    }
    return doc
}
```

When Notification Observer get that notification - Thus , the required function will be called itself

```
@objc func loadList(){
        //load data here    
    }
```

**Note** - Do not forget to remove added Observer When it is not required

**Second Option** 
Load Data When Operation is completed

```
public class func getProductsInShoppingList(name:String = "Default") -> DocumentSnapshot?{
            let db = Firestore.firestore()

            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let userId: String! = defaults.string(forKey: "UserUUID")

            var doc:DocumentSnapshot?
            db.collection("shoppingLists")
                .whereField("users." + userId, isEqualTo: true)
                .whereField("name", isEqualTo: name)
                .limit(to: 1)
                .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                            doc =  document
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                //Load data here
                            }
                            break
                        }
                    }
            }
            return doc
        }
```

Comment: This approach assumes my function is in the same class. I have a service class where I want to return the document. I can put this function in my controller but was hoping not to.

Comment: then you can just use notificationObserver i.e get data in any class just update notification to load data

Comment: I wound up using the userInfo in the notification. I assigned my object to the dictionary of user info in my notifications. Then my observer function in the parent class got it passed in via the notification parameter.